# JSX Conditional Rendering Undefined Variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am using JSX on for creating a front end page, however I am encountering a "is not defined" error which is causing my front-end not to load. I am retrieving userInfo from the back end, and there is a specific value, streakLength, that I want to use for conditional Rendering. I am declaring another const, onStreak, which is initialized to false, but set to true if streakLength is >= 3. The issue is, this onStreak const is being read as undefined and is causing my page to crash. I would honestly prefer is there was a way to simply perform the >= operation inside the html, but this was the workaround I was attempting. Please find the code below, and any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
const [surveyNotification, setSurveyNotification] = useState([]);
const [onStreak, setOnStreak] = React.useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {

        const userInfo = await AuthService.getUserInfo();
        // This retrieves the top 30 users based of points
        setSurveyNotification(await UserService.getNotifications(userInfo.id));
        
        console.log(surveyNotification);
    
        if(parseInt(userInfo.streakLength) > 2){
          setOnStreak(true);
        }
  
        console.log(onStreak);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

This is the JSX

```
<li className="nav-item dropdown pe-2 d-flex align-items-center" >
                <a href="javascript:;" className="nav-link text-white p-0" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style={{ paddingBottom: "-100px", marginLeft: "10px" }}>
                { onStreak ?  <span> userInfo.streakLength</span> : <span></span>}
                </a>
              </li>
```

and finally my error, which occurs at the conditional statement above "onStreak? ...."

```
WARNING in [eslint]
src\components\topNavbar\index.js
  Line 232:19:  'onStreak' is not defined  no-undef

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

Comment: and what exactly is on line `Line 232:`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss OH mb ofc, line 232 is the conditional statement in the html, I'll edit the question

Comment: With out thinking this late in the day my time it seems to indicate the WARNING is in `src\components\topNavbar\index.js`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes you are correct, that is where the above code is located. My issue is I don't know why the value is returning as undefined even when I initialize it to false above.

Comment: so is this line 232? `console.log(onStreak);`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss no, line 232 is { onStreak ?  <span> userInfo.streakLength</span> : <span></span>}

Comment: How it this code structured? Is it in one file inside same function? Could you show whole file?

Comment: That's a warning from es-lint, specifically this rule: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-undef. It's possible that your JSX is not in the same scope as `onStreak`. You'll need to show the whole file. It's probably not that nothing is loading, you're probably creating an empty span, because `onStreak` is falsey.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure without seeing the component as a whole, but are you sure `onStreak` is the problem? The error you posted is just a warning, so it shouldn't make your page crash.

As for this part:

```
{ onStreak ?  <span> userInfo.streakLength</span> : <span></span>}</a>
```

This would just display the text `userInfo.streakLength`, as it should be `{userInfo.streakLength}`, so maybe there is something wrong there.